# Query multiple facebook posts insights

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-insights

I'm now querying a post's insights with

```
/$postId/insights/post_impressions,post_impressions_unique
```

but if I want to have the insights of multiple posts, is there a way to achieve that with a single api call?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found that you can query the insights of multiple posts with a GET request like

```
/insights/post_impressions,post_impressions_unique?<id1>,<id2>,<id3>...
```

however you can reach the url length limit for GET requests, if someone knows a POST version that works it would be better